# Why my fscanf does not read the first string but reads the last line into the first string instead?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm a beginner at files including code so please someone help me. This is what my code looks like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define first_ten_hours 7.99;
#define after_ten_hours 1.99;

double charges_all(int hour);
double charges_avg(int money, int hour_use);
double round_money(double sum);

int main()
{
    FILE *f_read, *f_write;

    f_read = fopen("usage.txt", "r");
    f_write = fopen("charges.txt", "w");

    if(f_read == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error to open the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char date[2][10];
    char studenid[10][100];
    double using_hour[10];
    int current_line = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if(current_line == 1)
        {
            fscanf(f_read, "%s %s", date[0], date[1]);
            current_line++;
        }
        else
        {
            fscanf(f_read, "%s %lf", studenid[i], &using_hour[i]);
            current_line++;
        }
    }

    current_line = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if(current_line == 1)
        {
            printf("%s %s\n", date[0], date[1]);
            current_line++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s %lf\n", studenid[i], using_hour[i]);
            current_line++;
        }
    }

    fclose(f_read);
    fclose(f_write);

    return 1;   
}
```

After the `current_line = 1;`, I print to check and see the problem.

This is my text file.

```
12 2022
18010 4.5
92052 3.2
01051 7.4
11052 6.3
13052 5.5
01081 2.2
65052 1.3
94052 2.8
32052 3.7
41051 4.9
```

and this is the output from the `printf` loop:

```
41051 2022
18010 4.500000
92052 3.200000
01051 7.400000
11052 6.300000
13052 5.500000
01081 2.200000
65052 1.300000
94052 2.800000
32052 3.700000
41051 4.900000
```

But what I want is for the first string at the first line to be 12.

Comment: read studenid[i-1] if you want to fill 0 to 9, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way you have written your `for` loop(s), you are accessing elements of the `studenid` and `using_hour` arrays that are out-of-bounds on the last iteration of those loops (i.e. when `i` is 10 – an element at `[10]` is past the end of an array declared with 10 elements). Such "bad access" causes **undefined behaviour**, which may (as it appears in your case) include overwriting the value you had previously read into the `date` array elements.

A "quick fix" is to change the `[i]` indexes (all of them) to `[i - 1]`. However, a better way would be to put the read of the first line outside the loops and then run those loops for the next 10 lines:

```c
int main()
{
    FILE* f_read, * f_write;

    f_read = fopen("usage.txt", "r");
    f_write = fopen("charges.txt", "w");

    if (f_read == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error to open the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char date[2][10];
    char studenid[10][100];
    double using_hour[10];

    fscanf(f_read, "%9s %9s", date[0], date[1]); // Read first line differently
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Run the loop ONLY 10 times ...
    {
        fscanf(f_read, "%99s %lf", studenid[i], &using_hour[i]);
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", date[0], date[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %lf\n", studenid[i], using_hour[i]);
    }

    fclose(f_read);
    fclose(f_write);

    return 1;
}
```